# How to get full name of specific Subreddit of Reddit

Tags: ios, objective-c, reddit

Presently, I am working on Reddit app. A user can subscribe or unsubscribe from my app which will reflect to the respective account as well.

I am using [ReddKit](https://github.com/samsymons/RedditKit).

Now, I am stuck in getting a subreddit *Full name* field which is required to subscribe or unsubscribe by calling `subscribeToSubredditWithFullName` method. But, I am not able to extract *Full Name* from the response as an identifier error is being returned.

```
Response = "RKSubreddit: 0x7******60, full name: t5_***eq, name: politics"
```

Can anybody help in getting the *Full Name* of a subreddit?
Is there any other way to subscribe to a subreddit ?

Comment: Fixed grammar and formatting. Make sure to wrap your code block and links with the correct formatting.

Comment: I am sorry the answer is not clear. Can you please explain me in detail? It will be really helpful.

Comment: Read the [How To Ask Guide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks for the guide. I will definitely read that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working on Reddkit, I found the answer that we can call "**linksInSubredditWithName**" method and if we need sub-reddit "**full name**" then it will be available in ***RKLink.h*** which will be accessible by an object of ***RKLink***.